# Como validar que un usuario existe o esta registrado en BD? Angular

Tags: angular, validación, backend, frontend, union

Buenas tardes tengo la siguiente duda , tengo dos campos : username y contraseña los cuales quiero saber como puedo validar si existen en la base de datos , como puedo formular la condicion en este codigo no tengo conocimiento alguno en angular , esto quiero hacerlo con el motivo de que solo los usuarios registrados sean los unicos que pueden entrar al ambiente de la aplicacion de lo contrario si es un usuario invalido no pueda ingresar al ambiente

Como tal el Front se maneja en Angular y el Backend en python , el puerto de python es el 8000 ya se encuentra enlazado a los servicios de usuario de angular , lo unico que no tengo conocimiento es hacer funcional la logica de validacion en Angular

Estos son mis archivos principales para poder hacer el consumo de usuarios en la base para encapsularlos al acceso **login => dashboard**:

```
login.component.ts


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UsuarioService } from 'src/app/services/usuarios.service';
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { LoginI } from 'src/app/models/login.inteface';
import { UsuariosI } from 'src/app/models/usuarios.inteface';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router, private loginService: UsuarioService, private alerta: ToastrService) { }


  private user: any = {
    username: 'test',
    contrasena: '123456'
  }
  public loginForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    contrasena: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  })


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onLogin(form: LoginI) {

    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      console.log(form);
      localStorage.setItem('username', 'true');
      this.loginService.postLogin(form).subscribe();
      let Usuario: UsuariosI = {
        nombre_empleado: "daancabo",
        correo: "danielcaicedo285@gmail.com",
        usuario: "daancabo97",
        contrasenia: "contraseña123",
        rol: "2"
      }
      this.loginService.postToken(Usuario).subscribe(data => { console.log(data) })
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      this.alerta.success("Bienvenido")
    } else {
      this.alerta.error("Complete los campos", "Error")
    }
  }



  public login(data: any) {

    if (data.username && data.contrasena) {
      localStorage.setItem('username', 'true');  
      return this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }
    return alert('Usuario o contraseña invalidos');

    // /* Hacer un servicio que lea el api como las credenciales que se estan pasando en este formulario
    // Cuando se reciban , hay que almacenarlos en un sitio */

  }






}
```

```
código
```

```
login.component.html

<div class="hold-transition login-page">
  <div class="login-box" animate__animated animate__fadeOut>
    <div class="login-logo">
      <a href="login.component.html"><b>LOGIN VESPOT</b></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Inicio Formulario Login -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body login-card-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Bienvenido a Vespot SAS</p>
        <a href="./login.component.html" class="brand-link">
          <img src="./assets/dist/img/LogodeVespot.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="img-circle elevation-4 "
            style="opacity: .8" style="width:30%;margin-left:35%">
        </a>
        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin(loginForm.value)">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control"  placeholder="Usuario">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-envelope" style="color: rgb(48, 37, 37);"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="password" formControlName="contrasena" class="form-control"  placeholder="Contraseña">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-lock" style="color: rgb(48, 37, 37);"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4" style="margin-left: 74%;">
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-light" [disabled]="this.loginForm.invalid">Entrar</button>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="icheck-primary">
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember"> -->
                <!-- <label for="remember" class="ml-2">
                  Recordar inicio de sesion
                </label>  -->
              <!-- </div>
            </div> -->
            <!-- Iniciar sesion-->
            <!-- <div class="col-4" style="margin-left: 74%;">
              <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-light" [disabled]="this.loginForm.invalid">Entrar</button>
            </div> -->
            <!-- Iniciar sesion -->
          <!-- </div> -->
        </form>

        <div class="social-auth-links text-center mb-3 " id="my-signin2">

        </div>
        <!-- Adicionales -->

        <p class="mb-1">
          <a href="forgot-password.html" class="badge badge-light">Recordar contraseña</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- Adicionales -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fin Formulario login -->
</div>
```

```
login.interface.ts


export interface LoginI {
    nombre_usuario:string
    contrasenia:string
}
```

```
usuario.interface.ts

export interface UsuariosI {
    nombre_empleado:string
    correo:string
    usuario:string
    contrasenia:string
    rol:string
}
```

```
usuario.services.ts


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { ResponseI } from '../models/response.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UsuariosI } from 'src/app/models/usuarios.inteface';
import { LoginI } from 'src/app/models/login.inteface';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' 
}) 

export class UsuarioService {

  _url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
  // _url = 'http://173.82.187.142:81'


  postLogin(from:LoginI):Observable<ResponseI>{
    let heads = this._url + "/login" 
    return this.http.post<ResponseI>(heads,from);
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  postUsuario(form:UsuariosI):Observable<ResponseI>{
    let header = this._url + "/create"
    return this.http.post<ResponseI>(header,form);
  }

  postPassword(form:UsuariosI):Observable<ResponseI>{
    let header = this._url + "/change_password"

    return this.http.post<ResponseI>(header,form);
  }
 
  postLogout(form:UsuariosI):Observable<ResponseI>{
    let header = this._url + "/logout"

    return this.http.post<ResponseI>(header,form);
  }

  postToken(form:UsuariosI):Observable<ResponseI>{
    let header = this._url + "/token"

    return this.http.post<ResponseI>(header,form);
  }

  getUsersMe(form:UsuariosI):Observable<ResponseI>{
    let header = this._url + "/users/me/"

    return this.http.post<ResponseI>(header,form);
  }

  


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En general la forma mas simple es con interceptores que pueden modificar la comunicación entre tu app y el servidor pudiendo usar en ese circuito para la autentificación a un Token Web Json ` https://medium.com/@insomniocode/angular-autenticaci%C3%B3n-usando-interceptors-a26c167270f4` ejemplo --`https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-jwt-authentication/` si decides aplicar interceptores para autentificación y Tenes alguna duda decime

Comment: no estoy entendiendo nada de lo que dijiste

Comment: por eso te pase los links para poder entender como aplicar interceptores adios

Comment: me puede servir para almacenar los usuarios de la base de datos a ese acceso de login?eso es lo que yo necesito

Comment: El los links esta descripto una forma mediante token